# Sharepoint Online: How to display internal corporate websites, without HTTPS?

Tags: sharepoint-online, security, https, internal-server-error

We have several *internal web applications* that do not require the `HTTPS` protocol, as they are purely accessible internally within our intranet. Obviously with Sharepoint Online, our websites will not work.

Is there a way to "mask" the http protocol inside an `iframe` or some other web part that will allow us to by-pass the `https` requirement?

Yes, I understand accessing Sharepoint **outside of our network** infrastructure will not allow users to use these internal websites, but that's ok, as staff are only allowed to use them internally.
Thank you

Comment: I don’t think you can...as per msdn documentation. Only secure web sites can be embedded. Make sure the URL of the web site begins with HTTPS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even if it will be just usual site I guess that browsers will alert the users, that some part of content goes through http on https page, here is an example - [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18327314/how-to-allow-http-content-within-an-iframe-on-a-https-site]. So even if MS allows this, its easier to just have this certificate, than without it, the other thing that inside your organization you can use self-signed certificate, just to have "https".